# MySQL user privileges not working when using IP

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

I have the current setup:

SVR01:
Ubuntu Trusty, with Xen

VM01:
IP: 192.168.0.10
Ubuntu Trusty, with Apache2 + php modules

VM02:
IP: 192.168.0.11
Ubuntu Trusty, with mysql server

When I try connecting from VM01 (The apache server) to mysql on VM02, I get the "Access Denied for 'NewUser'@'192.168.0.10' (Using password: YES)" error.

I created the user using:

```
CREATE USER 'NewUser'@'192.168.0.10' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
GRANT EXECUTE ON mydb.* TO 'NewUSer'@'192.168.0.10';
```

But, it will work if I create the user using the host wildcard:

```
CREATE USER 'NewUser'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
GRANT EXECUTE ON mydb.* TO 'NewUSer'@'%';
```

Does anyone know why it won't work when I specify the host ip?

PS. I get the error when trying to connect either through the Mysql client, or through the PHP PDO.

Comment: Are you sure the IP seen by MySQL is the one you expect? Perhaps there are several network cards on the Apache server. Perhaps the virtualization alters the source IP. Please confirm this fact (eg. with `netstat`).

Comment: How do you trying to connect? from which machine?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Follow up questions:

- Does the grant seem to work if you create a user with a 192.168.0.% wildcard host mask?
- Run select user, host, password from mysql.user where user='NewUser' to ensure there's not another user@host you weren't aware of that might be getting picked up?
- Does the Access denied messages in your error logs confirm the failed connection attempts are in fact coming from the IP you think it is?  Some weirdness like this might pop up if you have multiple routes setup in a system that has multiple network interfaces or perhaps some VPN routes in the mix.
- When attempting connections to VM02 are you using a literal IP address or a hostname?  If the later are you sure this is resolving to the IP you think it is from VM01 (you can verify using ping or just the host command from the command line)
- Run "show variables like 'init_connect';"  on the root account you were creating the users with.  If that value is not blank you will want to ensure the accounts of permissions required to execute whatever that value does hold.

Comment: Huh ... It's suddenly decided it wants to work now ... I didn't have any other NewUser@host except that one ... To get it working I just literally dropped the @'%' user, and created the @'ip' user ... I guess I'm just going to have to put it down to my stupidity ... But thanks for the help, sometimes all that is needed is an extra head lol